# Replace whole data for a key and drop old values

Tags: mysql

I want to replace whole data for a key every one minute:

Suppose we have a table like this:

| cid | uid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | c |
| ... | ... |

Now I want to replace all records with cid=1 with new values which is `b` and `c`;
I have two plans:

1. Remove all existing with `delete from table where cid=1` and then `insert into table values(1,b),(1,c)`;
2. Insert all new records by `insert ignore into table values(1,b),(1,c)` and delete old data which is not exist in new values `delete from table where cid=1 and uid not in (b,c)`

I can use partitioning in mysql on cid which causes fast delete of data but I'm not sure if there is a better method since this happens every minute with thousands of values. I want the best method with minimum time and lowest cost (CPU+DISK+Blueprint). I need something like overwrite a file with new content every minute (**We don't need old data anymore**).

any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a complete set of new values for the table each time, or just for a specific cid?

Comment: every time for a specific cid but it repeats for all cids subsequently.

Comment: Depending on data volumes and your concurrency needs, you might also consider a third option: clone the table structure (only), and fully populate the new table with the new data, then exchange new and old tables

Comment: Thanks @RobEyre. I thought about that but my volume is huge and the number of different cids may be high. If I clone just one table for all cids it may causes inconsistency in data, because the data producer may crash.

Comment: Ah, just seen your comment.  I've posted an answer below - although it may not be useful in your case, it may be helpful for others finding this thread

Comment: No problem. Although it is not my answer but It is a good solution as is. I vote up it.

Comment: Another thought: you might be able to optimise plan 2 with an additional monotonically increasing 'update_num' column, which you could then index.  ie for update number 100 you could do `INSERT INTO mytable (cid, uid, update_num) VALUES (1, 'b',100),(1,'c',100),... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE update_num = 100` then `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE cid = 1 AND update_num < 100`.  It might make plan 2 a little bit faster.  (If you're going to be updating all the cids, you could even postpone the `DELETE` call to the end and do them all at once)

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobEyre. I also thought about that. But it needs you to save the last update_num for each cid and you need retrieve it when you select. It also need additional column (disk) and I said best method with respect to CPU+DISK+Blueprint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maximise read access and have a full dataset you can load at once, then you might consider a possible third option:

- create an empty clone of the original table

  CREATE TABLE mytable_new LIKE mytable;
- populate your new table with a full dataset.  There are different ways you could do this, depending on where your new data is coming from.  `LOAD DATA` is pretty efficient if your data is already on the server, or you could use batches of `INSERT INTO mytable_new VALUES (1,'a'),(1,'b'),...` statements if your data is coming via an application layer, or, if your new data is already elsewhere within MySQL tables, `INSERT INTO mytable_new SELECT ...`
- do an atomic rename of your old and new tables

  RENAME TABLE mytable TO mytable_old, mytable_new TO mytable;
- finally, clean up by dropping your old data

  DROP TABLE mytable_old;

Comment: I thought about that but my volume is huge and the number of different cids may be high. If I clone just one table for all cids it may causes inconsistency in data, because the data producer may crash. Although it is not my answer but It is a good solution as is.